# Is it usual that output to STDERR is not decoded?

Tags: perl, character, encode, dbi, stderr

When I run this script (or similar scripts with DBD::SQLite or DBD::MySQL), it looks like the returned error-messages are not decoded.
Is it usual that output to STDERR is not decoded?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:Pg:dbname=my_test_db", 'username', 'password', {
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 1,
    AutoCommit => 1,
    pg_enable_utf8 => 1,
} ) or die DBI->errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "S☺LECT * FROM abteilung" );
$sth->execute();
```

Output:

```
#DBD::Pg::st execute failed: FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei Â»SâºLECTÂ«
#ZEILE 1: SâºLECT * FROM abteilung
#         ^ at ./perl2.pl line 16.
```

Comment: Are you sure your output console supports that encoding? Does STDIN output correctly?

Comment: STDIN outputs correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a case of double-encoding. The driver encoded your query using UTF-8, then included that query in the error message you then (properly) encoded for output.

Comment: Can I fix this without disabling `binmode STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)';`?

Comment: You'd have to look at the driver, but doubtful.